# How to beautifully display the data obtained from postgres (node js) in the table?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, postgresql, ejs

After the request in postgres

```
 `
        router.get('/index', (req, res, next) => {
       pool.connect(function (err, client, done) {
           if (err) {
               console.log("Can not connect to the DB" + err);
           }
           client.query('SELECT * FROM cdr_final WHERE info_init @> \'{"subscriber":"9999999999"}\' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20', function (err, result) {
                done();
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    res.status(400).send(err);
                }

                res.render('index', { cdr: result });
           })

       })
    });`
 I get the data in jsonb format

{"command":"SELECT","rowCount":18,"oid":null,
"rows":[{
        {"id":754210,"info_init":{"Hour":"10","Time":"10:34:27",...,"subscriber":"99999999999",},"info_final":{"Shift":115,"OutCome":0,...,},"state":1},
        {"id":754210",info_init":{"Hour":"10","Time":"10:34:27", ... "subscriber":"99999999999",},"info_final":{"Shift":115,"OutCome":0, ..."WorkMode":48,},"state":1}
    }]
    }
```

, I need
put this data in a table in index.ejs. Since only not long ago began to get acquainted with
Node js how to do it yet do not represent, in advance
thank you all for your help.